# Cannot access NodePort service outside Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop, wsl-2

I am on Windows and used Docker Desktop to deploy a local Kubernetes cluster using WSL 2. I tried to deploy a pod and expose it through a NodePort service so I could access it outside the cluster, but it is not working.

Here are the commands to reproduce the scenario:

```
kubectl create deployment echoserver --image=k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.4
kubectl expose deployment echoserver --type=NodePort --port=8080
```

Trying to open `NODE_IP:EXPOSED_PORT` in the browser or running the netcat command `nc NODE_IP EXPOSED_PORT` and trying to send a message (from either WSL or Windows) does not work.

- `NODE_IP` is the internal IP of the Docker Desktop K8S node (obtained by seeing the `INTERNAL-IP` column on the command `kubectl get nodes -o wide`)
- `EXPOSED_PORT` is the node port exposed by the service (obtained by seeing the field `NodePort` on command `kubectl describe service echoserver`)

Opening the URL on the browser should be met with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8hPk.jpg) page. However, you will get a generic error response saying the browser couldn't reach the URL.

Sending a message with the netcat command should be met with a 400 Bad Request response, as it will not be a properly formatted HTTP request. However, you will not get any response at all or the TCP connection may not even be made in the 1st place.

Trying to communicate with the service and/or the pod from inside the cluster, for example, through another pod, works perfectly.
Using the command `kubectl port-forward deployment/echoserver 2311:8080` to port forward the deployment locally and then either accessing `localhost:2311` in the browser or through netcat also work perfectly (in both WSL and Windows).

Comment: When you describe the service, is there an external IP assigned?

Comment: The `IP` field of the service says `10.96.23.195`. I do not see anything saying external IP. Is that supposed to be another field?

Comment: You should be able to access via localhost:nodeport (make sure you're targetting the actual nodeport, not the container port). If it doesn't work, I would guess it's something on the host machine (windows) blocking it.

Comment: How did you bootstrap your cluster? Was it kind/minikube?

Comment: @mmking I have tried that. It did not work

Comment: @Marius I just enabled the kubernetes cluster option on Docker Desktop. Docker Desktop is the one bootstrapping it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access it not using localhost you should use your `<windows_hosts's_IP:NodePort>`.

So having your deployment and service deployed:

```
$kubectl get svc,deploy
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/echoserver   NodePort    10.105.169.2   <none>        8080:31570/TCP   4m12s
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          5m3s

NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/echoserver   1/1     1            1           4m19s
```

You can either access it by using `localhost:31570` or <windows_hosts's_IP:NodePort>.

In my case `192.168.0.29` is my Windows host's IP:

```
curl.exe 192.168.0.29:31570
CLIENT VALUES:
client_address=192.168.65.3
command=GET
real path=/
query=nil
request_version=1.1
request_uri=http://192.168.0.29:8080/
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what happened, but now I can communicate with the pod from outside the cluster using both localhost and Window's host's IP! However, I still have an issue related to this. To avoid going off track on this post, [I created a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66296434/pod-udp-hostport-not-working-in-docker-desktop) if you want to have a look