# Pod UDP hostPort not working in Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, udp, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am using Docker Desktop for Windows with WSL2 and I am trying to deploy the following Deployment to my Docker Desktop's Kubernetes cluster:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: udp-listener
  labels:
    app: udp-listener
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: udp-listener
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: udp-listener
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: udp-listener
        image: mendhak/udp-listener
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5005
          hostPort: 5005
          protocol: UDP
```

It is a simple container that exposes a UDP listener on port 5005. The container logs every UDP message it receives. It also exposes that port to outside the cluster on port 5005 of the host too.

The problem I am having is that when I try to connect to the UDP port from Windows using `nc localhost 5005`, it does not work. However, if I instead try to expose the container port using a `NodePort` service with the command `kubectl expose deployment udp-listener --port=5005 --name=udp-listener-svc --protocol=UDP --type=NodePort` and then run `nc localhost EXPOSED_PORT`, it works perfectly and I see every UDP message I send in the container's logs.

What is even stranger is that this does not seem to be an issue with TCP ports: if I try to deploy a TCP listener pod--instead of a UDP one--, change the protocol of the pod's `hostPort` to TCP, and then connect to it using the same netcat command from Windows, it works! It also works with a TCP `NodePort` service.

**TL;DR:**

- I can communicate from outside the cluster with a pod running a **TCP** listener container that is exposed through the container's `hostPort`
- However, I cannot communicate from outside the cluster with a pod running a **UDP** listener container that is exposed through the container's `hostPort`

Comment: Hello, I'd reckon you will need to wait for MS response, whether the `UDP` protocol is officially supported in `WSL2`. Link: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4825#issuecomment-755954946. Also please check the suggested workaround included in this thread.

Comment: Is the issue the same? From what I can tell, the user in that thread with the issue can send UDP messages from Windows to a listener in WSL2 and see those messages on WSL2. He just can't track them with a tool like Wireshark. In my case, the UDP messages sent from Windows are not arriving at my pod's container in WSL2 at all, as they do not show up in the logs

Comment: I just tried using the `sudppipe` tool suggested in that thread with `sudppipe -x -b 0.0.0.0 WSL_IP hostPort 5754`, and then using `nc -u localhost 5754` so the UDP packet is forwarded from the tool to WSL and it still does not work